# Как вмешиваться в оперативную память других процессов?

Tags: c++, c

Подскажите что почитать на русском чтобы понять как внедряться в оперативную память. Допустим есть игра с чатом, я бы хотел добавить сообщение в чат на клиенте. Как я понимаю, мне нужно найти этот участок памяти, сдвинуть всё что было назад и в конце этого участка добавить свое сообщение. Но как мне находить размер этого участка и так далее. Заголовков конечно же нет. Может инструменты какие-то известные существуют для такого.

Был бы рад если бы вы привели пример на `C/C++`:

- Первая программа просто выводит массив из строк по требованию(например нажатию любой клавиши)
- А вторая вмешивается в работу и первой и добавляет в этот массив свою строку

Comment: Тут важна ОС...

Comment: Думаю, что решить описанную задачу тем способом, который описан в вопросе, не получится. Дело в том, что размещение и обработка данных впроцессе - - довольно неочевидно. Хотя, некотрые читы для игр работают именно на таком принципе.

Comment: @S.H. Понятное дело что тут всегда индивидуальный подход. Но было бы интересно взглянуть на решение из той задачки что я описал, когда есть сорсы.

Comment: @SKIP Ну на примере win10x64

Comment: а точно нужно на С++?

Comment: @DrMcSheen Нет, главное принцип сам

Comment: ArtMoney прекрасный инструмент

Comment: @DrMcSheen для поиска адреса может быть, но важен же автоматизм. Конечно оффсеты сначала нужно найти, захардкодить

Comment: сюда код не вставляется. В ответ написал

Comment: @SergeySergeev почитайте про ReadProcessMemory. Можете посмотреть как пишут читы для кс го на ютубе на С++ их там полно.

Comment: Это невозможно. Почитайте про защищённый режим. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Защищённый_режим#:~:text=Защищённый%20режим%20(режим%20защищённой%20виртуальной,была%20реализована%20страничная%20организация%20памяти.

Answer (score 4):

Вот у меня проект на С++, писаный лет 10 назад, читал и модифицировал память чужого процесса.
Я уж ничего оттуда не помню, гугли по кускам кода

```
HANDLE hProc;
PROCESSENTRY32 pe;
MODULEINFO modinfo;
hProc = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS,0);
pe.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
if(Process32First(hProc,&pe))
      {
      do {
            if(strcmp(exeName,pe.szExeFile) == 0)
                 {
                 hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ,     false, pe.th32ProcessID);
                 char szFilePath[255] = {0};
                 GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, NULL, szFilePath, 255);
                 GetModuleInformation(hProcess, 0, &modinfo, sizeof( modinfo ) );
                 edEntryPoint->Text = IntToHex((int)modinfo.EntryPoint,8);

             DWORD nread=0;
             if(ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID)i, &Mem_buf, 4, &nread))
                {
                edJmpMyBlock->Text = IntToHex(Mem_buf[0],8);
                }



if (hProcess == NULL)
     {
     if (GetLastError() != ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED) return false;
     OSVERSIONINFO osvi;

     // определяем версию операционной системы
     osvi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(osvi);
     GetVersionEx(&osvi);

     // мы больше ничего не можем сделать, если это не Windows NT
     if (osvi.dwPlatformId != VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT)
        return false;

     // включим привилегию SE_DEBUG_NAME и попробуем еще раз

     TOKEN_PRIVILEGES Priv, PrivOld;
     DWORD cbPriv = sizeof(PrivOld);
     HANDLE hToken;

     // получаем токен текущего потока
     if (!OpenThreadToken(GetCurrentThread(),
                         TOKEN_QUERY|TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES,
                         FALSE, &hToken))
        {
        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_TOKEN) return false;

        // используем токен процесса, если потоку не назначено никакого токена
        if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(),
                              TOKEN_QUERY|TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES,
                              &hToken))
            return false;
        }

     _ASSERTE(ANYSIZE_ARRAY > 0);

     Priv.PrivilegeCount = 1;
     Priv.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
     LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_DEBUG_NAME, &Priv.Privileges[0].Luid);

     // попробуем включить привилегию
     if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &Priv, sizeof(Priv), &PrivOld, &cbPriv))
        {
        dwError = GetLastError();
        CloseHandle(hToken);
        return false;
        }

     if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED)
        {
        // привилегия SE_DEBUG_NAME отсутствует в токене
        // вызывающего
        CloseHandle(hToken);
        return false;
        }

     // попробуем открыть описатель процесса еще раз
     hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);
     dwError = GetLastError();

     // восстанавливаем исходное состояние привилегии
     AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &PrivOld, sizeof(PrivOld), NULL, NULL);
     CloseHandle(hToken);

     if (hProcess == NULL) return false;
     }

if (!WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID)BufParam, &dat, 256,    NULL))
     return true;
```